# See who is current user in a ssh terminal session in FreeBSD 12

Tags: freebsd, users

When using a terminal session via ssh to a FreeBSD 12 server, how can I verify the name of the user in that session?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## `id`

If you just need to identify your username from within the terminal session, use [`id(1)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=id)

For example:

```
id -p
```

> uid    freebsd
>
> groups freebsd wheel

This command complies with [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX), and supplants the [`whoami`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=whoami+&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD+12.0-RELEASE+and+Ports&arch=default&format=html) utility.

Answer (score 3):

Two easy ways are with the `w` or `who` command. They will tell you who is logged in and what terminal device they are using.

```
$ w
11:46PM  up  3:23, 2 users, load averages: 1.45, 0.94, 0.71
USER    TTY FROM              LOGIN@  IDLE WHAT
user1      p0 :0.0              9:01PM     0 -ksh 
user2      p1 :0.0             11:42PM     0 w
```

```
$ who
user1      ttyp0    Jul 11 21:01   (:0.0)
user2      ttyp1    Jul 11 23:42   (:0.0)
```

To see who you logged in as, use `logname`.

To see what user you currently are, you can use `echo $USER` or `whoami`.

Comment: How do I know which user listed is the user of my session?

Comment: Does using `who` presume I am a superuser? Can regular users see a list of who is logged in?

Comment: Any user can see who is logged in with `who`. I'm confused why you need the user of your session. The target user you specified with ssh and the time your ssh'd in should be enough evidence to know which user you are. Another way to know what user you currently are is a simple `echo $USER` or `logname`.

Comment: As for why, I might have multiple terminal sessions open and lose track of which is which. Or I might open a “Console” VNC session as a backdoor access to a cloud VM such as DigitalOcean and not be fully aware of what user automatically established the session.